# How to generate Chrome Extension's popup body based on periodically fetched data?

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, dom, google-chrome-extension

I am programming a Chrome Extension that will be fetching JSON data every minute and update the popup's html body (accessible after clicking the icon) based on the results.

This is my background.js:

```
var lastResponse = ""; //Here I save the JSON I receive

function generateTable() { //This function generates the html body table
    console.log('Generating table');
    var resp = JSON.parse(lastResponse);

    var headers=new Array("", "last", "buy", "sell", "15m", "24h");

    // creates a <table> element and a <tbody> element
    var tbl      = document.createElement("table");
    var tblBody = document.createElement("tbody");

    // creating all cells

    var row = document.createElement("tr");
    for (var i=0;i<6;i++)
    {
        var cell = document.createElement("td");
        var cellText = document.createTextNode(headers[i]);
        cell.appendChild(cellText);
        row.appendChild(cell);
    }
    tblBody.appendChild(row);


    for(var key in resp){ {
        // creates a table row
        row = document.createElement("tr");

        for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            // Create a <td> element and a text node, make the text
            // node the contents of the <td>, and put the <td> at
            // the end of the table row
            var cell = document.createElement("td");
            if (i==0) {
                var cellText = document.createTextNode("");
            } else {
                var cellText = document.createTextNode(key);
            }
            cell.appendChild(cellText);
            row.appendChild(cell);
        }

        // add the row to the end of the table body
        tblBody.appendChild(row);
    }

    // put the <tbody> in the <table>
    tbl.appendChild(tblBody);
    // appends <table> into <body>
    document.body.appendChild(tbl);
    // sets the border attribute of tbl to 2;
    tbl.setAttribute("border", "2");
}

function readBlock() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", "https://blockchain.info/ticker");
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            if (xhr.status == 200) {
                lastResponse = xhr.responseText;
            }
        }
    }
    xhr.send();
}

function onAlarm(alarm) {
    if (alarm && alarm.name == 'refresh') {
        readBlock();
    }
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  generateTable();
});


chrome.alarms.create('refresh', {periodInMinutes: 1.0});
chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener(onAlarm);
readBlock();
```

When I try to run this, I get an error of

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input background.js:82

Line 82 being the last line of the .js. I am guessing I am having problems because I try accessing the JSON before it is available. How should I go about making this program work properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You getting that error because the `function generateTable()` is not closed...

Well, it is, but in line 26 you have `for(var key in resp){ {` ... that's an extra `{` and is causing a malformed javascript function. (unclosed)

Fix that line and tell us if that was the only problem.

Good luck whith your project.

---

***Edit***: (new info update)

Pass the json variable to the function and double check that has the correct format.
I will suggest also, to use the `try` function...

```
   // your JSON data as string
   var lastResponse = '{"id":1, "color":"red"}';
   // the function...
   function generateTable(jsonString){
      ...some code...
      ...some code...
      try {
         var resp = JSON.parse(jsonString);
      } catch (e) {
         // return false if the string can't be parsed to json
         console.log('error found:' + e);
         return false;
      }
      // looking good, go ahead!
      ...some code...
      ...some code...
   }
   // and last, call the function with the JSON string in it:
    generateTable(lastResponse);
```

and finally and as always, good luck and keep trying ;-)

Comment: Hmm, now it states - "Unexpected end of input" at `var resp = JSON.parse(lastResponse);`, which means it tries to parse JSON that is not there most likely...

Comment: Try to pass the json var to the function like: `function generateTable(jsonString){...var resp = JSON.parse(jsonString);...}` and then, call the function with `generateTable(lastResponse)`